# Read repository source code files through the Ruby git gem?

Tags: ruby, git

I want to get access to a repository's source code through [the git gem](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git). My goal is to go through the source code files and read their content.

From [the examples](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git#examples) it's unclear to me how I do this? I get the sense that I need to use `Git.open`, as shown here:

```rb
g = Git.open(working_dir, :log => Logger.new(STDOUT))
```

But it's not clear to me what `working_dir` is. If I was to target the [github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git) project there are many ways to reference it. It could be any of these:

```
git@github.com:ruby-git/ruby-git.git
https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git.git
https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git
```

So please let me know if you know how I read the source code files from a repository.

Comment: I think you have to clone the repo first and `working_dir` refers to the local directory on your machine where you cloned the project. Could you give that a try?

Comment: @mbuechmann what would be the command for cloning? Or to be more specific, what would be the path to clone from?

Comment: Either do `git clone <URI>` on your command line, or use `Git.clone` from the git gem (see examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`working_dir` is directory of your project with Git.

Says your project is in the `/home/john_smith_1976/awesome_project` folder.

In this case use

```
require 'git'
g = Git.open('/home/john_smith_1976/awesome_project')
```

After that for example you can use `g.grep('some_code')` etc.

Comment: Thanks @mechnicov, ok so the `working_dir` refers to a local path. But my question is rather how to retrieve code from a remote location, such as Github.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976, just look at the sources of this gem, this gem didn't read from remote location. You need to download or clone repo first.

Comment: So there is no way to read a remote repo?